# Is open relay to local users the right way to work on port 25?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

today i was checking my server Postfix restrictions when i realized anyone who meets a very basic requirements like not being in a black list, also anyone who communicates to the server properly, etc. is able to send emails to local users through port 25 without issuing any kind of authentication.

I mean, one of the last restrictions in main.cf smtpd_*_restrictions is reject_unauth_destination - the very next one is greylisting in my case - so anyone who's delivering to local accounts and bypass the greylisting is going to be able to send email to local users without any kind of authentication.

As i'm really new to Postfix and for sure it looks pretty strange/insecure - but on the other hand i do not know another way to let unknown hosts communicate between them, i'm wondering if that's the right approach to use?

I also given a a look at some howtos and them all follow the exposed approach.

```
http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/#config-simple-mta
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixCompleteVirtualMailSystemHowto
...
```

Could anyone clarify if that's the right way to work? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You are using the term "open relay", but what you describe is normal delivery to local users. An open relay would accept messages that are destined for users on an arbitraty third, remote host. This, of course, must be prohibited.

Comment: If you want a server to receive email for arbitrary users at a domain, from arbitrary senders, then it's going to have to allow anyone to connect to its port 25 and deliver mail **to that domain**.  There's no way around that, unless you hope that people will call you on the 'phone and pre-arrange a time and source ip address for each piece of mail they want to send you.

Answer (score 2):

That's how mail is normally delivered when you have an MX entry pointing at the machine, or the machine has a FQDN and you email user@FQDN.

It all depends if you want to run a mail server accepting inbound mail or just deliver locally generated mail off the machine to somewhere else.

Comment: Could you please briefly explain the alternate methods? Thanks!

Comment: Well, you could *not* accept mail (firewall port 25), which is sensible if your users aren't humans reading mail on the machine with 'mutt' or similar UNIX clients and you aren't running imapd etc. What are you trying to achieve with this postfix server?

Comment: I'm just trying to get and deliver email for a private corporation.